# Found a component written 'RCs' on the package. What is this component?

Tags: identification, components, test-equipment

[image]

While I was tearing down a broken sampling scope in the lab, I found two of 'RCs' components in the sampling scope head module. I tried to look up the information about this component, but couldn't find any information regarding this.

Can anyone share with me what this component is supposed to be doing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [Infineon BFP193W](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2305101756_Infineon-Technologies-BFP193WH6327XTSA1_C672128.pdf) bipolar RF transistor.

[image]

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot!